# console.log into different terminal window - node.js

Tags: node.js

In our nodejs project, there are several pages of debug info logged into one default console window for each HTTP request. It is very difficutlt to find out the info that is logged by me.

I am not at liberty to edit other part of the code in this project. I'd like to to create a new terminal window and only log my debug info to this window.

**Question**: 
It is possible to do it [using console.log](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html) along? If not, anyway to launch a new terminal window and log my info there? I think nodejs can control local file system and call OS functions. There must be a way.

Thanks!

Comment: console.log into stdout or stderr. Can we provide another stdout to this function?

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom `Console` objects:

```
var Console = require('console').Console;
var fs = require('fs')

var stream = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/mylog');

var console = new Console(stream, stream);

var i = 0;

(function log () {
  console.log(i++);
  setTimeout(log, 1000);
} ())
```

Then just do `tail -f /tmp/mylog`

Comment: writing to file is my current solution. But can I launch a new terminal window? Then log the info in the new window?

Comment: https://github.com/flatiron/winston winston looks like a very good log tool. Do you know if it allows me to log into 2 different terminals?

Comment: nothing allows to do that directly. Your process has only one std output stream and it is associated with a single terminal instance. You need some other program to be executed in a new terminal window to have access to it: for example `tail`

Answer (score 0):

Use a different log. [Winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) supports tons of log formats as well as multiple logging channels. Instead of sending your debug info to the console, send it to a file. You can read it later or `tail -f` it in real time.